# ¿Cómo añadir datos a sesión cuando un usuario inicia sesión? Symfony

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony

estoy aprendiendo Symfony y me preguntaba como puedo hacer para, cuando un usuario inicie sesion, insertar como variable de sesión información que tengo en una base de datos.

Quiero hacer que cuando un usuario inicie sesion, automaticamente tenga los productos que eligio (los cuales estan en la base de datos) en su carrito de compra (basicamente, que los productos añadidos no se pierdan cuando cierre sesion).

He intentado hacerlo desde el archivo LoginController.php y AuthenticationUtils, pero no lo consigo. ¿Tienen idea de como puedo conseguirlo? No se si esta es la mejor manera de hacerlo, si no lo es, pueden aconsejarme otra sin problema.

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final lo he conseguido. Para ello simplemente he añadido en el método `OnAuthenticationSuccess`, en `LoginFormAuthenticator.php` el código que necesitaba:

```
 public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, string $firewallName): ?Response
{

    $currentuser= $this->security->getUser()->getId();
    $usercart = $this->em->findOneBy(['id' => $currentuser])->getCartItems();
    $request->getSession()->set("idproducts", $usercart);
    if ($targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $firewallName)) {
        return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
    }

    // Show Exception:
    // throw new \Exception('TODO: provide a valid redirect inside '.__FILE__);
    return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('register'));
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Imagino que estás desarrollando una especie de tienda online y te has topado con la funcionalidad de permitir que el usuario compre sin estar autenticado en la plataforma, hace un tiempo tuve que desarrollar algo similar, aquí te dejo mi idea.

Lo que hago inicialmente es llamar al método `generateAnonymusOrder()` en el momento que el usuario acceda al apartado donde puede comprar algo, seguido a eso comienzo a cargar en la variable de sesión creada todos los **ID** de los ítems que vaya añadiendo al carro de compras, **Importante no guardes el objeto completo en la sesión ya que puedes afectar el rendimiento de tu web.** En el momento que intenta acceder al carro para pagar entonces le solicito que se autentique, *esto protegiendo la url en el firewall de **Symfony** te vale*. Una vez autenticado y accediendo al carro, bajo de la sesión todos los id de los ítems que tiene cargado, los busco en la base de datos y creo una orden a la que se los asocio. Te dejo el código que utilicé, ya te digo es un poco antiguo pero si tienes dudas lo comentamos.

```php
 public function generateAnonymusOrder()
    {
        if (is_null($this->session->get('anonymusItems')))
            $this->session->set('anonymusItems', []);
    }
```

```php
public function getOrderActive()
    {
        !is_null($this->session->get('orden')) ? $result = $this->em->getRepository(Orders::class)->find($this->session->get('orden')) : $result = null;
        return $result;
    }
```

```php
private function CreateItemBasked($pitem)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $item = $em->getRepository(Pricelist::class)->findOneBy(array('itemid' => $pitem));
        $price = $item->CalculatePrice($this->getUser());
        $orderActive = $this->getOrderActive();
        $orderskus = new Orderskus();
        $orderskus->setSku($item->getItemid());
        $orderskus->setProductname($item->getDescriptionforsales());
        $orderskus->setQuantity(1);
        $orderskus->setUnitprice($price);
        $orderskus->setoriginPrice($item->getRetail($this->getUser()));
        $orderskus->setOrdersOrderid($orderActive);
        $em->persist($orderskus);
        $em->flush();
    }
```

```php
 private function ProcessItem($pitem, $user = null)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $orderActive = $this->getOrderActive(); 
        $item = $em->getRepository(Orderskus::class)->findOneBy(array('sku' => $pitem, 'ordersOrderid' => $orderActive));
        if (is_null($item)) {
            $this->CreateItemBasked($pitem);
        } else {
            $item->setQuantity($item->getQuantity() + 1);
            $em->persist($item);
        }

        $em->flush();
    }
```

```php
private function ProcessAnonymusItem(Request $request)
    {
        $session = $request->getSession();
        $sessionItem = $session->get('anonymusItems');
        if (!empty($sessionItem) && count($sessionItem) > 0) {
            foreach ($sessionItem as $item) {
                $this->ProcessItem($item, $this->getUser());
            }
            $session->remove('anonymusItems');
        }
    }
```

```php
public function showShoppingCartAction(Request $request)
    {
        $session = $request->getSession();
        $data = []
        if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {

            if (is_null($this->getUser())) {
                $count = count($session->get('anonymusItems'));
            } else {
                $this->ProcessAnonymusItem($request);
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $order = $em->createQuery('SELECT SUM(o.quantity) as cant FROM Orderskus o WHERE o.ordersOrderid = :orderActive')
                    ->setParameter('orderActive', $this->get('app.services')->getOrderActive())->getResult();
                if (!is_null($order))
                    $count = $order[0]['cant'];
            }

            $count > 0 ? $data['notification'] = '<i class="icon-basket-loaded" style="font-size: 25px; !important;"><span class="badge badge-info">' . $count . '</span></i>' : $data['notification'] = '<i class="icon-basket"></i>';
        }
        return new JsonResponse($data, 200);
    }
```